# If $2a^2+8b^2+5c^2=2c(a+6b)$ then find $a:b:c$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

It's a question involving three variables $a, b$ and $c$. One just has to find the ratio of the three variables.

Comment: What have you tried?  Don't answer in a comment -- edit your question to show what you've tried.  People don't tend to respond well here to questions that don't demonstrate an independent effort to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried finding any one variable in terms of others but can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Are $a,b$ and $c$ *real* valued or something else ?

Comment: a,b and c have real values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 8 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 6 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 8 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

To get zero as $v^T D v$  if and only if the column vector $v$ is of the form $(0,0,t)^T$ for some real number $t.$ Then $Pv$ is of the form $(t/2,3t/4,t)^T$ or, letting $t = 4s,$ of form $(2s, 3s, 4s)^T$

Your proportion notation would say
$$ 2 : 3 : 4  $$

Comment: What is this method called?

Comment: @John1085  see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Subtract and complete two squares.

Answer (score 1):

$$5c^2-2c(a+6b)+2a^2+8b^2=0$$

The discriminant of the quadratic equation in $c$

is $$4(a+6b)^2-20(2a^2+8b^2)=\cdots=-4(3a-2b)^2\ge0$$

If $c$ is real  $3a-2b=0\implies \dfrac a2=\dfrac b3=k$(say)

and consequently $$c=\dfrac{a+6b}5=\dfrac{2k+6(3k)}5=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to transform the given equation using

$$u= \frac ac, v= \frac bc \Rightarrow 2u^2 - 2u +8v^2 - 12 v +5 = 0$$

Square completion gives

$$2\left( u - \frac 12 \right)^2 + 8\left( v - \frac 34 \right)^2 = 0$$

It follows with $a : b = u : v = 2:3$

$$a:b:c = 2 : 3 : 4 $$